# Android Webview Video not working

Tags: android, html, video, android-webview

I build a little Android library in Eclipse, that open new Activity, put inside it WebView and load into WebView html page with video. I'm using WebView like:

```
 webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            if (newProgress == 100) {
                showContentOrLoadingIndicator(true);
            }
        }

    });
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

and

```
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/mobile/player/" + VeediUtils.GAME_ID + "/" + ((JSONObject)VeediUtils.LEVELS.get(gameLevel - 1)).getInt("unique_id") + ".html" + ((debugState == 0) ? ("") : ("?debug=veedi")));
```

Next step, I had built new project, added my first project like a Android dependency, and all works ok, how it should. But when I gave my library to other developer (I don't have access to his code) and he added it like Android dependency to his project, he found an issue: there is he hear sound but instead of video he see black screen. So here the question: what it can be in his application, that break my video in WebView? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The webview does not properly support HTML5 video.

**See [here](https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView) for a library** for proper video support.

If the video is in flash format, it will not work on android 4.4 and up. Otherwise, the user needs to have flashplayer installed, and you need to enable plugins in your webview.

Comment: No, I'm using *.mp4 format only, and here the issue: that video is shown in my project but isn't shown in his project in the same devices... P.S. thanks for this library I will check.

Comment: That's strange, it should work if its on the  same device. Did he modify the code in some way? Maybe you could try to remove the setWebViewClient method from your webview, as it does not seem to be doing anything?

Comment: No, he has only my compiled classes. And I need "setWebViewClient", because I need its method "shouldOverrideUrlLoading", because of that device not asking from user first time: to choose browser for my url in WebView.

Comment: using `webView.loadUrl()` in your will always load your url in the webview, it will not ask to load in another app or browser.